# VBA, search string within a formula in excel

Tags: string, excel, vba, search, text

Is it possible to search specific text in a formula using vba?  For example: I have a bunch of index(array match(array,"criteria"0),0) and other sum formulas. I want to search formulas with "index" and change cells color.

Thus far I have written the following code:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'color cells having formulas
    If cell.HasFormula Then 
        Find = "*index*" 
        cell.Font.Color = indexcolor
    End if
Next cell
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can use the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method to look through formulas and then you can use `c.Interior.Color = vbRed` to highlight the cells. The above link even includes the VBA code you need (pre-written by Microsoft for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Changecellcolor()

Dim formulaColor As Long
Dim cell As Range

LinkedCells = RGB(Red:=0, Green:=0, Blue:=255)

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If InStr(1, cell.Formula, "index") > 0 Then
    cell.Font.Color = LinkedCells
    End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub LookinForDory()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        s = LCase(r.Formula)
        If InStr(1, s, "index") > 0 Then
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```